# Was the Vedic commentator Sayana a Vaishnava?

Tags: vaishnavism, sayanacharya

I am talking about the [Vedic commentator Sayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayana).

Was he known to be a Vaishnava?

Comment: He is a neutral commentator. He is not a Vaishnava,

Comment: He was Advaitin, brother of Vidraranya of Sringeri peeta,

Comment: Adavaitin means he was not a Vaishnava? @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sayana was an Advaitin and brother of Madhava (generally believed to be pre-ascetic name of Sri Vidyaranya). Sri Vidyaranya played a crucial role in formation of Vijayanagara Empire.

Three brothers  Madhava, Somanatha, Sayana were born in Brahmin family of Mayana. [Sri Vidyatirtha](https://www.sringeri.net/jagadgurus) told the brothers to [complete remaining works](https://www.sringeri.net/jagadgurus/sri-vidyaranya/biography) in their name with unfinished Veda Bhasyas.

> It was at this time that the two brothers, Madhava and Sayana, the
> sons of Mayana of Bharadwaja Gotra, approached Sri Vidyaranya and
> sought his blessings. Sri Vidyaranya graciously gave them his
> unfinished Veda bhashyas and some other works. He blessed them to
> complete the works in their own names as Madhaviyam and Sayaniyam.
> Later, both the brothers served as ministers in the Vijayanagara
> empire under Bukkaraya and Harihara I and II.

[Dr.B.R Modak](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/ancillary-literature-of-atharva-veda-study-with-special-reference-to-parisistas-NAF480/), a professor of Sanskrit who edited Swarajya Siddhi (a manual of Advaita Vedanta), says Sayana gives Advaita Vedanta interpretation for [philosophical hymns](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2rL1RtLr2KkC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=sayana%20advaita&source=bl&ots=F-ZdASUbUx&sig=zUeyDQg74hYa_Vt199HWvUGODx0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM4OOGvtXaAhUHsY8KHabdAS4Q6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=sayana%20advaita&f=false):

> When Sayana comments on a philosophic hymn, he interprets it according
> to the view of Advaita Vendanta. Thus he explains
>
> Rigveda 1.86.10 as follows :
>
> 'Destroy the positive ignorance which is in the cave (heart)  of the
> body. Remove all the desire, anger etc. which devour the  values ot
> life. (Purushartha). Give the light of knowledge in the  form of the
> realisation of the Highest Reality
>
> While commenting on the Creation Hymn (Rigvedax.129)
> the word asat as,
>
> 'indescribable like the horn of a hare'  and he
> explains the word sat as 'which can be described as existent  like the
> Atman'. The word svadha is explained as maya (Cosmic  Power).

Comment: Ok but does that imply that he was not a Vaishnava?

Comment: @Rickross  Philosophically he follows Advaita Vedanta like his brother Sri Vidyaranya. But i don't know his Ista Deva but in any case Sayanacharya's Bhasya is neutral and mostly Advaitic.